# How do I get the first group of alpha characters from string?

Tags: c#, regex, split

If I have a string how do I extract the first alpha characters from the string such that I end up with the starting alpha characters or an empty string. E.g:

```
AB12 9HG => "AB"
PJ11 => "PJ"
123JO => ""
```

Is this possible with regex or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to build the result:

```
new String(s.TakeWhile(p => Char.IsLetter(p)).ToArray());
```

Basically, just take the characters from the start until the first non-alpha char.

If there is leading whitespace, `Trim()` the string first.

Comment: See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/4M1I9Y). BTW, a regex to get the initial letters is `@"^\p{L}*"`, but here, you can get what you need with non-regex means - unless you want to only restrict to some specific script.

Comment: Nice, some "micro-optimizations": you can use `TrimStart` instead of `Trim` and you can use `s.TakeWhile(Char.IsLetter)`

Comment: Yes, `TrimStart` looks more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example (https://dotnetfiddle.net/CiIaqx):

```
    var inputs = new [] { "ASD123", "PJ11", "123JO" };
    foreach (var input in inputs) 
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(input, "^([a-z]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Checking: " + input + ", found: " + match.Groups[1].Value);
        }
    }
```

This outputs:

> Checking: ASD123, found: ASD
>
> Checking: PJ11, found: PJ
>
> Checking: 123JO, found:

Answer (score 1):

Another LINQ approach that let's you define a whie list of accepted characters is following. Create a `HashSet<char>` once like this:

```
private HashSet<char> _alphas = new HashSet<char>("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
```

Now you can use this simple and efficient LINQ query:

```
string result = string.Concat(input.TakeWhile(_alphas.Contains));
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be something like this:

```
^([A-Za-z])*
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple with regular expressions.  Just anchor with `^` then match zero or more with `*` of the characters you want `[A-Za-z]`.

```
var inputs = new[] { "AB12 9HG", "PJ11", "123JO" };
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z]*");

foreach (var x in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x + " => \"" + regex.Match(x).Value + "\"");
}
```

outputs

> AB12 9HG => "AB"
>
> PJ11 => "PJ"
>
> 123JO => ""

Answer (score 0):

I was using a `Portable Class Library` so didnt have access to the `TakeWhile` method on a string, (or not that I could see).

I therefore extended the idea from Wiktors answer and came up with an extension method for my string:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string GetStartChars(this string s)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        {
            s = s.TrimStart();
            foreach (var letter in s.ToCharArray())
            {
                if (char.IsLetter(letter))
                {
                    result += letter;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

use it like:

```
var startChars = "AB11".GetStartChars();
```